# Regex for capturing word separated terms

Tags: regex

I have several Strings that I am trying to parse with regex in the following format:

`FIELDA`:wiz AND `FIELDB`:foo AND `FIELDB`:bar AND `FIELDB`:baz.......

the `FIELDB`:(some value) pattern will be present 0 to N times, always separated by the term `AND`. `FIELDA` is always present

Is there a regex pattern that I can use to capture all of the values:

```
wiz, foo, bar, baz
```

Comment: You might as well use `(?<=:)\w+` since you don't care about anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookarounds based regex and match all the values you want using this regex,

```
(?<=FIELD[AB]:)\S+(?= AND|$)
```

**Regex Explanation:**

- `(?<=FIELD[AB]:)` - Positive look behind to ensure matched text is preceded by either `FIELDA` or `FIELDB`
- `\S+` - Matches one or more non space text
- `(?= AND|$)` - Positive look ahead to ensure matched text is either followed by `AND` or end of string using `$`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4i4qOv/1)**

**[Java Code Demo](https://rextester.com/DVFK38741)**

```
String s = "FIELDA:wiz AND FIELDB:foo AND FIELDB:bar AND FIELDB:baz";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=FIELD[AB]:)\\S+(?= AND|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Prints,

```
wiz
foo
bar
baz
```

Comment: The demo works, but when I try this in my Java program, it doesn't seem to work. Is there any changes that I would have to make to do this with java pattern matching, outside of escaping the backslash?

Comment: @user1154644: Can you share your Java codes? Make sure you escape `\S` as `\\S`

Comment: @user1154644: I've added Java code demo in my answer, you can check. It should help you locate the problem in your code.